# How get value from this code by using Selenium?

Tags: c#, asp.net, selenium, testing

I want this value 201607000044 to string from this code -

```
<SPAN id=ctl00_ctl00_ctl00_ctl00_ContentPlaceHolderCenter_ContentPlaceHolderBody_ContentPlaceHolderBody_ContentPlaceHolderBody_txtNumber class=inputBold style="WIDTH: 200px; DISPLAY: inline-block">201607000044</SPAN>
```

Because this is not working -

```
IWebElement notificationNumberElement = FindElementById("ctl00_ctl00_ctl00_ctl00_ContentPlaceHolderCenter_ContentPlaceHolderBody_ContentPlaceHolderBody_ContentPlaceHolderBody_txtNumber");
        string notificationNumber = notificationNumberElement.GetAttribute("value");
```

Comment: What is `FindElementById`? and what do yo mean by "not working"?

Comment: FindElementById is my function. is equal driver.FindElement(By.Id("ctl00_ctl00_ctl00_ctl00_ContentPlaceHolderCenter_ContentPlaceHolderBody_ContentPlaceHolderBody_ContentPlaceHolderBody_txtNumber")); Not working means i dont get this value to string.

Comment: Do you have any errors?

Comment: string is null exception

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `.Text` as below :-

```
IWebElement notificationNumberElement = driver.FindElement(By.Id("ctl00_ctl00_ctl00_ctl00_ContentPlaceHolderCenter_Conte‌​ntPlaceHolderBody_ContentPlaceHolderBody_ContentPlaceHolderBody_txtNumber"));
string notificationNumber = notificationNumberElement.Text;
```

if your `id` is dynamically generated try using `CssSelector` as below :-

```
IWebElement notificationNumberElement = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("span.inputBold"));
string notificationNumber = notificationNumberElement.Text;
```

Answer (score 1):

The value is text. You can get it with `Text` member

```
string notificationNumber = notificationNumberElement.Text;
```